# change the position of the button when cursor is placed on it

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, mouselistener

so what i have to do is make button but user cant click on it, every time the user points on that button the button changes its position.
i am trying to get the position of the cursor and then comparing it with the positon of the button and if they are equal the button moves to a random position but this not working...
any help

```
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me)
{
Point p = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
x=p.x;
y=p.y;
i=b2.getBounds().x;
j=b2.getBounds().y;

Random d=new Random();
a = d.nextInt(200);
b = d.nextInt(200);

if (x==i && y==j){
b2.setLocation(a,b);
}

}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate what you are trying to say? i didnt understand??sorry i am new to java

Comment: Sorry, I misread the example. Ignore what I said.

Comment: If I were the user, I'd tab to the button and hit enter.  But then I probably would not be a user of such a silly program..

Answer (score 0):

`b2.getBounds()` contains the x, y, width, and height of the button. In your code, you're checking for when the mouse cursor is at the same x y location. However, this will only be true when the cursor is on the top right corner of the button. What you really want to do is check for when the cursor is WITHIN the bounds of the button. For example:

```
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me)
{
Point p = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
x=p.x;
y=p.y;
i=b2.getBounds().x;
j=b2.getBounds().y;

Random d=new Random();
a = d.nextInt(200);
b = d.nextInt(200);

boolean withinX = x >= i && x <= i+b2.getBounds().width;
boolean withinY = y >= j && y <= j+b2.getBounds().height;

if (withinX && withinY){
    b2.setLocation(a,b);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be better off adding a `MouseListener` to the button, and use `mouseEntered`. It will effectively have the same result as what you are trying to achieve

```
private Random d = new Random();
private JButton button = new JButton("Button");

button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
         int a = d.nextInt(200);
         int b = d.nextInt(200);
         button.setLocation(a, b);
    }
});
```

The problem with using a `MouseMotionListener` for the container of the button, is that the button will swallow the mouse event of the container. So trying to check if the point from the mouse event is inside the button will never be successful.

Here's a test case for what I mean about the button swallowing the mouse event. You can see that the it prints when the mouse is anywhere but over the button

```
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class NewSwingTemplate {

    private Random d = new Random();

    public NewSwingTemplate() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JButton button = new JButton("Button");
        MyPanel panel = new MyPanel(button);
        panel.add(button);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

        public MyPanel(final JButton button) {

            addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (button.getBounds().contains(e.getPoint())) {
                        System.out.println("contains");
                        int a = d.nextInt(200);
                        int b = d.nextInt(200);
                        button.setLocation(a, b);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(e.getPoint());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewSwingTemplate();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

And here's an example where it works the way you want it to.

```
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class NewSwingTemplate {
    private Random d = new Random();

    public NewSwingTemplate() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(createButton());
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JButton createButton() {
        final JButton button = new JButton("Button");
        button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                int a = d.nextInt(200);
                int b = d.nextInt(200);
                button.setLocation(a, b);
            }
        });
        return button;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewSwingTemplate();
            }
        });
    }
}
```